# Can't save data in the Firebase database - React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have already installed and import firebase in the project, the code looks like this:

```
componentWillMount(){
  var config = {
    apiKey: "***************************",
    authDomain: "configuracaofirebase-3a6ef.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://configuracaofirebase-3a6ef.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "configuracaofirebase-3a6ef",
    storageBucket: "configuracaofirebase-3a6ef.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "939162871117"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

salvarDados(){
  var database = firebase.database();
  database.ref("pontuacao").set("100");
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button 
        onPress={ () => { this.salvarDados() } }
        title="Salvar dados"
        color="#841584"
        accessibilityLabel="Salvar dados"
      />
      <Text>Meu App</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

does not work when I call the "salvarDados" method

show this error:

```
typeError: undifined is not a function (evaluating '_app.default.database()')
```

Comment: please remove your API from this post and regenerate one from firebase. DO NOT POST YOUR API KEY ANYWHERE

Comment: try changing `salvarDados()` to `salvarDados = () => {}`

Comment: I already answered with a possible solution for your question on https://pt.stackoverflow.com, you should check that

Comment: I tried, but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

I solved it just by adding a new import:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/database';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the {} around the function call:

```
onPress={ () => { this.salvarDados() }
```

Will become:

```
onPress={ () => this.salvarDados() }
```